# How to export zpool from alternate disk slice?

Tags: zfs, solaris-10, zpool

I need some help in recovering ZFS pool. Here is scenerio. There are two disks -
c0t0d0 - This is good disk. I cloned it from other server and boot server from this disk.
c0t1d0 - This is original disk of this server, having errors. I am able to mount it on /mnt. So that I can copy required data from this to c0t0d0

Below pool is not imported yet and copy of another server, from where I have cloned

```
# zpool import
  pool: zplctpool
    id: 11623878967666942759
 state: DEGRADED
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
action: The pool can be imported despite missing or damaged devices.  The
        fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised if imported.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
config:

        zplctpool          DEGRADED
          mirror      DEGRADED
            c0t0d0s7  FAULTED  corrupted data
            c0t0d0s7  ONLINE
```

I do not want this zplctpool, it can be deleted. Instead, I want zplctpool, which is sitting on c0t1d0s7

Regards

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Which disk is mounted, which has errors, what have you done already? Are there two separate pools or are both disks from zplctpool?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely follow what you're trying to accomplish, but the end goal seems to be to move a zpool from one system to another.

The first warning is that you probably didn't issue a `zpool export` on the drive from the other system.

I'm perplexed that your pool is listing a mirror across c0t0d0s7 and itself (c0t0d0s7).  When you say you cloned a drive, did you mirror?  To do that, you need to split the mirror to make both drives usable--which I think is a new feature in Solaris 11.